# Amplify get Hosting URL in lambda as environment variable

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I need the URL of Cloudfront distribution that I added with amplify cli as an environment variable.
Status:
[image]

I found how template variables are added in file "api-cloudformation-template.json" under my function config.
Desired Output variable from "hosting/S3AndCloudFront/template.json" is `CloudFrontSecureURL`.
So I added rows to lambda config file, like so:

```
 {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Lambda resource stack creation using Amplify CLI",
    "Parameters": {
        ...
        "hostingS3AndCloudFrontHostingBucketName": { // working example
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "hostingS3AndCloudFrontHostingBucketName"
        },
        "hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL": { // my example
            "Type": "String",
            "Default": "hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL"
        },
    },
    "Resources": {
        "LambdaFunction": {
            "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
            "Metadata": {
                "aws:asset:path": "./src",
                "aws:asset:property": "Code"
            },
            "Properties": {
                ...
                "Environment": {
                    "Variables": {
                        ...
                        "HOSTING_S3ANDCLOUDFRONT_HOSTINGBUCKETNAME": {
                            "Ref": "hostingS3AndCloudFrontHostingBucketName"
                        },
                        "HOSTING_S3ANDCLOUDFRONT_CLOUDFRONTSECUREURL": {
                            "Ref": "hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL"
                        }
                    }
                },

            }
        }
    ....
    },
    ....
}
```

I'm getting `hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL` (default value) in `process.env.HOSTING_S3ANDCLOUDFRONT_CLOUDFRONTSECUREURL` after publishing function.

Comment: can you post the tutorial that you are following, you are trying to pass the 'cloudfront' url to the lambda as environment variable, but you are not getting it, because the parameter is not getting passed during the deployment via amplify, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) section of the template along with Fn::ImportValue function documentation [HERE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

CloudFront Stack:

```
{
   ...
   "Outputs" : {
     "CloudfrontDomainOutput" : {
       "Description" : "The cloudfront domain",
       "Value" : { 
           "Fn::GetAtt": [
                           "hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL",
                           "DomainName"
                          ]
       },
       "Export" : {
         "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL" }
       }
    }
}
```

Lambda Stack

```
{
  ...
   "Environment": {
       "Variables": {
               "HOSTING_S3ANDCLOUDFRONT_HOSTINGBUCKETNAME": {
                   "Ref": "hostingS3AndCloudFrontHostingBucketName"
                },
                "HOSTING_S3ANDCLOUDFRONT_CLOUDFRONTSECUREURL": {
                      "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${CloudFront_Stack_Name}-hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL"}
                }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: It won't work. Because `hostingS3AndCloudFrontCloudFrontSecureURL` is a parameter. We refer parameters using `ref`. What do you say

Comment: @ArunK You're right, thanks for pointing that out, i have updated my response, are you able to do a cross stack reference?

Comment: the syntax looks fine, for this to work, the `cloudfront` must have been created using cloudformation and the url should be exported.